# Can't use the setSelectionRange method for HTMLInputElement

Tags: typescript

Hi I'm currently working with the caret of a textbox and I need to use setSelectionRange for type `HTMLInputElement` but I don't get a suggestion for this method from visual studio. Am I missing some type of library? I do have `HTMLInputElement` class just not this method.

Thanks!

Comment: Please incorporate some sample code into your question in order for others to fully understand what you are talking about. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `HTMLTextAreaElement` interface. The method simple does not exist on `HTMLInputElement`

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement)

Comment: I started using the HTMLTextAreaElement but no matter which class I use, Visual Studio doesn't recommend me the correct methods. It always recommends generic methods.